# WebSocket Server: Is Close Always Called?

Tags: networking, websocket, connection

I'm building an iPhone app called AcaniChat. The server uses Node.js ws module. Can I assume that the Node.js ws close callback function is guaranteed to be called for every connection that ends? What if all of a sudden, I blew up my iPhone with a grenade? Would close get called on the server?

Answer (score 0):

No. If the client closes its socket, the TCP connection would be closed, but the server socket would remain "open", although any further operations on the socket would result in an error (or an indication that the client closed the connection).

If the phone was blown up with a granade, the TCP connection wouldn't be closed gracefully, and any further operations on the server socket would result in an error (one different from the error if the client closed its socket).

So a close on a socket does two things: it closes the connection (if it isn't closed already), and releases any local system resources used for the socket object. So you should call close in all cases.

Comment: Sorry. I'm talking about the node ws close callback function.